# HashMap UUID or String as key?

Tags: java, string, hash, uuid

```
HashMap<UUID/String, Object>
```

Which is better? I know UUIDs dont use that much memory but what is generally better to use?

Comment: For *what* purpose? It's like asking what ball to use while not specifying the sport you're playing.

Comment: Why *not* a string key (and what is the content)? Why *would* a UUID be  better?

Comment: string could be a name

Comment: What programming language?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

UUID takes up less space than the String does. Storing UUID itself via `HashMap<UUID, MyObject>` will conserve the space compared to `HashMap<String, MyObject>`.

Comment: what about sorting stuff

Comment: A UUID takes up less space than "hello world"?

Answer (score 6):

In general, the more specialized a type, the less waste there is, both regarding algorithms and storage.
Also, the data gets easier to manipulate.

Thus, if you know your argument is always a UUID, don't go for strings instead.

Ignoring that advice leads to a loosely typed mess, in extreme cases also known as **stringly-typed-programs**.

http://blog.codinghorror.com/new-programming-jargon
http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?StringlyTyped

[image: cat with strings]