# Is it a good idea to set the date in to a varchar in sql?

Tags: sql

Later on Im going to count the record for every month in year

Comment: No.  All databases provide a `date` data type for a reason.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24888297/6471538 (starring the data structures anti-pattern design kitty)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's generally better to use stronger data types rather than weaker ones.  They help you catch invalid inputs, and they stronger signal to your developers and your future self what the column is meant to hold.  VARCHAR can hold basically anything.

If you don't have a specific reason to make this column a VARCHAR, then I would strongly recommend `date`.

VARCHARs can also cause optimization problems down the road. Since you plan on counting and doing analysis on this column later, indexing and other features will likely better support you with the stronger casting.

And then there's the data bloat. With MySQL, if you're just storing a date, `2021-06-08` is 10 bytes, compared to the `date` of 4 bytes.  A date+time like `2021-06-08 14:03:23` is 19 characters at 1 byte each, while storing it in a `datetime` will be ~8 bytes (depending).  The savings are even bigger if you wind up storing fractional seconds.

If you want to read up more on the options for MySQL as one example, you can find them here: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-types.html